# How to pass list elements as function arguments to CDM::IRT.compareModels

Tags: r

Given a function with the following signature:

```
the_function(arg1, ...)
```

The following is a valid call:

```
the_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Now, assume that the arguments are stored in a list

```
my_list <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

How do I pass these arguments to the function?

`my_list |> the_function()` does not work, because (I assume) it is understood as `the_function(arg1 = my_list)`

---

Specifically, I want to use the function `CDM::IRT.compareModels`:

Extended example from the documentation:

```
data(sim.dina, package="CDM")
data(sim.qmatrix, package="CDM")

dat <- sim.dina
q.matrix <- sim.qmatrix

#*** Model 0: DINA model with equal guessing and slipping parameters
mod0 <- CDM::din( dat, q.matrix, guess.equal=TRUE, slip.equal=TRUE )

#*** Model 1: DINA model
mod1 <- CDM::din( dat, q.matrix )

list(mod0, mod1) |>
 IRT.compareModels()
```

Comment: Would it be an issue to use `the_function(unlist(my_list))`? If you could edit your question to be reproducible (ie, a minimally working function) we may be able to provide more accurate/specific help

Comment: @jpsmith I felt like this was a general problem (for me). I added the specific example. (`unlist` does not work here)

Answer (score 2):

Use `do.call` -

```
sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
#[1] 15

my_list <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
do.call(sum, my_list)
#[1] 15
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for, but somehow this does not work for `CDM::IRT.compareModels`. You might still want to keep this answer as a general solution for other functions?

Comment: @user1 I do think `do.call` may be useful here, it simply is a bit messier and you need to access the right parts - if you do: `xx <- do.call(CDM::IRT.compareModels, modlist)[[1]]; xx[,1] <- paste0("model", 0:1); xx` you will see a similar result as `CDM::IRT.compareModels(mod0, mod1)$IC` - good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith `xx[,1] <- paste0("model", 0:1)` is not working for me

Comment: @user1 I forgot to mention I stored both your models in a list `modlist <- list(mod0, mod1)` prior to running the above code